# JSON Data from a WebMethod

Tags: c#, json, webmethod

I have the following JSON string which has been returned from Webmethod.

```
[{"__type":"DEV.GlobalClasses+Class","AKA":["Peter Pan","Donald Duck"],"Countries":["US","UK"],"Gender":"Male","PercentageMatch":94},{"__type":"DEV.GlobalClasses+Class,"AKA":["Andrew"],"Countries":["FR"],"Gender":null,"PercentageMatch":72}]
```

I'd like to present it in a WebPage as follows:

```
 AKA
 Peter Pan
 Donald Duck

 Countries
 US, UK

 Gender
 Male

 Percentage
 79
```

With each set of data being presented as I would in a asp ListView.

I've come up with this so far, but i'm struggling to get the values of AKA, Countries.

```
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Default.aspx/PopulatePopUp",
                cache: false,
                data: JSON.stringify({ messageId: messageId, messageType: messageType }),
               // data: '{ messageId:' + messageId + ', messageType:' + messageType + ' }',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

            dataType: "json",

            success: function (msg) {

                var classes= msg.d;


                $.each(classes, function (index, class) {

               var table =          $("<table><thead><tr><th>AKA</th><th>Countries</th><th>Gender</th><th>Percentage</th></thead><tbody>");
                    var tr = "<tr>";


                    tr += "<td>" + joinWithBr(class["AKA"].string) + "</td>";
                    tr += "<td>" + joinWithBr(class["Countries"].string) + "</td>";
                    tr += "<td>" + class["Gender"] + "</td>";
                    tr += "<td>" + class["PercentageMatch"] + "</td>";

                    tr += "</tr>";
                    table.append(tr);
                });
                table += '</tbody></table>';
                $('div#results').html(table);

            }



            });

            function joinWithBr(arrayObj) {
                var str = "";
                for (var i = 0; i < arrayObj.length; i++) {
                    str += arrayObj[i] + "<br/>";
                }

                return str;
            }
```

*** EDIT ***

Ok, must of been the weekend heat, but i find some other errors this morning. She revised Jquery script below:

```
      success: function (msg) {

                    var entities = msg.d;
                    var table = $("<table><thead><tr><th>AKA</th><th>Countries</th><th>Gender</th><th>Percentage</th></thead><tbody></tbody></table>");
                    $.each(entities, function (index, entity) {

                        var tr = "<tr>";

                        $.each(entity["AKA"], function (index, ele) {
                            tr += "<td>" + ele + "<br/>" + "</td>";
                        });
                        $.each(entity["Countries"], function (index, ele) {
                            tr += "<td>" + ele + "<br/>" + "</td>";
                        });
                        tr += "<td>" + entity["Gender"] + "</td>";
                        tr += "<td>" + entity["Percentage"] + "</td>";
                        tr += "</tr>";
                        table.append(tr);
                    });
                    $('div#results').html(table);
```

So this now produces output as required, but the layout isn't as i'd like, not being a UI developer and all. How can I present the output in a ListView?

***EDIT ***

[image: Raw HTML]

[image: Display]

***EDIT***
Ok so the layout is now sorted, but for some reason, I get six entries, when there are only 3 data sets:
[image: results]

Comment: `class` is a reserved keyword in JavaScript. First change it with something else. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words

Comment: cheers Satpal, it's for illustration purposes in this forumn only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `$.each` on the arrays as well:

```
$.each(class["AKA"], function(index,ele){
    tr += joinWithBr(ele);
});
```

Ditto with 'countries'.

The relevant section of the code would finally look like:

```
                    var tr = "<tr><td>";
                    $.each(entity["AKA"], function (index, ele) {
                        tr += ele + "<br>";
                    });
                    tr+= "</td><td>"
                    $.each(entity["Countries"], function (index, ele) {
                        tr += ele + "<br>";
                    });
                    tr+= "</td>";
                    //Continue adding gender, percentage, etc.
```

Comment: I sha try that when I'm in the office. Thanks aquaraga

Comment: Aquarage that worked, just need a little help on formatting. See edit above, if you can help please

Comment: @CSharpNewBee I've edited by answer. Can you check if this works well for you?

Comment: Hmm, I don't think so. But you have to close the 'table' tag in the end - i.e. tr+="</table>". Can you try rendering the page now.

Comment: this is the produced output:

<tr>
 <td>
  <td>Name 1<br/>
  <td>Name 2<br/>
 </td>
 <td>
  <td>UK<br/>
  <td>US<br/>
  <td>FR<br/>
  <td>ES<br/>
 </td>
  <td>
</tr>

Comment: @CSharpNewBee Oops I hade made a typo. It should've been tr += ele + "<br/>";

Comment: @acquarage really appreciate your help on this, see the screen shots in the edit above. Almost there, got to sort out the heading and get rid of the last BR

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33473/discussion-between-aquaraga-and-csharpnewbee)

Comment: @acquarage see edit above. I get the layout I want now, but get six in stead of three representations of data